# How to divide lists and print the divided values to different files?

Tags: bash, sed

I'm writing a script which is designed to help me in dividing servers lists so when I'm releasing new versions of the company's products I won't have to disturb the service but only a portion of the servers, by implementing the changes on a divided list of servers each time.

The script is connecting to some internal dashboard and pulls the hostnames of the currently active servers (servers in rotation) and it's supposed to count the number of servers and based on rules which have been decided by the team, it should divide the lists to create smaller lists to work on.

So for example, if a certain data center contains 35 servers, I want the script to divide the big list to 4 not-equal lists, or if there are 10 servers I want it to divide the big list to 2 small lists.

Most of the script works already, and the only problem I have is with creating the small lists.

I'm using a `for loop` with the `seq` command as the counter up to the value of the `$divider` but then I'm not sure how to fill the file with the relevant lines from the big list.

Things I've already tried:

> `sed '1,$divider!d' big.list` -> In this case, it seems like I have a
>   syntax issue.
>
> `head -n` and `tail -n`.

```
#!/bin/bash
site="http://10.X.X.X/dashboard/company/DCD/dcd.aspx?dcd="
tmpfile="DCD.tmp"
echo "Choose DCD:"
select DCD in 'ams2' 'ny4' 'ny4a' 'lax'  'sg' 'Quit'; do
      wget $site$DCD -O $tmpfile -nv &> /dev/null
      grep http $tmpfile | awk -F"<" '{print $7}' | awk -F/ '{print $3}' | grep -v '^$' | sort | awk -F: '{print $1}' > "$DCD"_active.list
  #   echo site: $site , DCD: $DCD
      if [[ "$DCD" = "Quit" ]]; then
      exit 0
      fi
      break
done
srvnum=$(/usr/bin/wc -l $DCD'_active.list' | awk '{print $1}')
echo "<--- List of servers: --->"
  /bin/cat "$DCD"_active.list
echo "<--- Number of active servers: $srvnum --->"
if [[ $srvnum -lt "2" ]]; then
  echo "Not enough servers"
elif [[ $srvnum -ge "10" ]] && [[ $srvnum -le "20" ]]; then
  echo "It is recommended to divide the list by 2"
  divider="2"
elif [[ $srvnum -ge "21" ]] && [[ $srvnum -le "34" ]]; then
  divider="3"
  echo "It is recommended to divide the list by 3"
elif [[ $srvnum -ge "35" ]]; then
  echo "It is recommended to divide the list by 4"
  divider="4"
fi
#echo srvnum: $srvnum
#echo divider: $divider
entries=$(echo $srvnum/$divider | bc)
echo "Each list will contain: $entries entries"
  for i in $(seq $divider); do
    sed '1,\$i!d' "$DCD"_active.list
#head -n$entries "$DCD"_active.list > "$DCD"_$i.list
#tail -$entries "$DCD"_active.list > "$DCD"_$i.list
    done
```

**Edit #1:**

In the data center I'm checking the script on there 10 servers which means creation of 2 lists of 5 servers.
After editing the script to include the change @jofel added, two lists are indeed created but one of them contains only 1 line of the first server and the second list contains 2 servers which are the first and the second from the list, any idea why?

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes prevents the `variable substitution`. You should use `sed` with double quotes. And you also want to redirect the `sed` output (every time calculating starting and ending) to the files.

```
for i in $(seq $divider); do
    first=$(((i-1)*(srvnum/divider)+1))
    last=$((i*(srvnum/divider)))
    sed "$first,$last!d" "$DCD"_active.list > "$DCD"_$i.list
    done

modulo=$((srvnum%divider ))
if [[ $modulo -ne 0 ]]; then
  first=$((srvnum-modulo+1))
  sed "$first,$srvnum!d" "$DCD"_active.list > "$DCD"_$((divider+1))".list"
fi
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you did in $first and $last?

Comment: Because a chunk of sublist is extracted from the **active.list** in every step in the for loop. So you should calculate the beginning and the ending numbers of every sublist. For example if `srvnum` is 11 and `divider` is 2 then 5 sublists are (1,2) (3,4) (5,6) (7,8) (9,10)  and also remaining numbers (in this example 11) should be considered. see `modulo` @itai-ganot

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation.